# Java Generics : Convert Object Array to Primitive Array based on type

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I want to convert an Object array to primitive array based on type of elements present in array.

I want to implement a function which takes Object array and type(as String) as inputs and should return the actual array i.e

func(Object[] arr, String type) should be implemented so that when I call

func(Object[] arr, "int"), it should return int[]

func(Object[] arr, "double"), it should return double[] etc.

Is it possible to do this and if not what can be done to obtain primitive array from Object[] ?

Edit : The use case I have is I need to create 'n' objects of class A which has certain fields(lets say 2). I get fields as Object arrays of length n i.e

Object[] field1

Object[] field2

I also get type of field in String format("int" or "double" etc) which is primitive always. Now can we create objects of class A and if possible how?

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve? The problem here is going to be if you try to do it in one function, you cannot define a non-generic return type. If you create multiple functions, how do you cast it to a single object that is also not a generic? I think we need more context to better assist.

Comment: @JayMason I have added the use case I have. Maybe it gives better idea

Comment: Is it like Object[] will have n elements? Object[] field1 will have first field of all n objects and Object[] field2 will have second field of all n objects?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pre-allocating an array, I would suggest using a collection like ArrayList and then generate the resultant array into it.

```
ArrayList field1Array = Arrays.stream(arr).map(Object::field1)
```

If there are more fields that need to be allocated, then...

```
ArrayList field1Array = new ArrayList();
ArrayList field2Array = new ArrayList();
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(object -> {
  field1Array.add(object.getField1());
  field2Array.add(object.getField2());
})
```